# Git pull from remote branch to a new local branch, why I found a commit in the branch from which I stated the command?

Tags: git

Let' me explain what happened to me.

Current branch is koala-dev.
From this branch I invoked the command

```
 git pull origin preproduction:preproduction
```

Note that local branch preproduction didn't exist.

What I found:

- as expected a new local branch named preproduction synched with the remote branch w/ same name
- but also i found a new entry(commit) in the log of my koala-dev branch with :

  Merge branch 'preproduction' of x.x.x.x:/opt/git/myremoteproject into koala-dev

Why did this happened?

by statement: git pull [origin] [source]:[dest]

is it supposed to synch only origin/source--->dest? isn't it?

Comment: You should use `fetch` instead of `pull` if you does not want to merge into current branch.

Comment: I dont get much your point, I said I'm on my koala-dev branch, I need to create a new branch, same as the remote preproduction, isn't it possible to do it with one command? By fetching I won't create a branch.

Comment: `git fetch origin preproduction:preproduction`

Answer (score 2):

From: `git help pull` manual entry page we can read:

```
Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.
```

for updating only `preproduction` branch you need to checkout first `preproduction` then make the pull.